# Why can't I use Automator to correctly target UI elements in System Preferences? [ventura]

Tags: applescript, automator, system-settings, preferences, ventura

I'm trying to use Automator to record an action on the system preferences, in the accessibility display pane.  I want to change the value of the slider for the color filter intensity.

I use automator to Watch Me Do and record the action.  I reset the preferences manually. Clicking run does not cause the setting to change in preferences.

So I drag the actions from the Watch Me Do panel to the workflow timeline, which pop-out the action into an AppleScript.  Running this is also not successful.

Can I manually set this preference in some way via the cli?  When I search Apple developer docs, all I'm finding is Swift code to write an application.  ((I realize that the app that will do this change, Automator, Terminal, or otherwise, will need to be granted accessibility permissions under privacy/security system preferences.))

Or how do I get/write an AppleScript to do this?

[image: split image of automator (the result of its actions), and system preferences accessibility display pane]

---

Also, I have checked the OSAX dictionary for System Preferences, and it does not have more specific controls registered besides at the basic window/pane/etc level

[image]

---

I tried running the terminal command as `defaults write com.apple.mediaaccessibility MADisplayFilterSingleColorIntensity -float 0.25` but this did not change the Intensity slider, including when before/after toggling the Accessibility Colors Filters on/off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set it via Terminal by running

`defaults write com.apple.mediaaccessibility MADisplayFilterBlueColorCorrectionIntensity -float 0.25`

You can set the values for each filter independently by replacing `MADisplayFilterBlueColorCorrectionIntensity` with the one you want:

Red/Green: `MADisplayFilterRedColorCorrectionIntensity`

Green/Red: `MADisplayFilterGreenColorCorrectionIntensity`

Blue/Yellow: `MADisplayFilterBlueColorCorrectionIntensity`

Color Tint: `MADisplayFilterSingleColorIntensity`

The lowest value is 0.25 and the highest is 1.0.

Comment: That doesn't work. I can update with a screenshot, but the slider doesn't change.  Where did you find that info?  Was it docs, or something else?